# How do I Scaffold tables with EF.Core Database First containing special characters $

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have the following table in our SQL Server:

```
[prod].[dbo].[My Company$Customer]
```

I want to Scaffold this table with:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=SQLPROD;Database=prod;Trusted_Connection=True;integrated security=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -table "dbo.My Company$Customer"
```

But it will always give me the following error:

```
Unable to find a table in the database matching the selected table
```

If I omit the -table switch everything works fine, but I get ALL tables, which are A LOT and I don't need them. So how can I use the -table switch correctly?
I am using ef.core 2.2.1

Comment: Have you tried `-table "[dbo].[My Company$Customer]"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, if you have special characters in your table names (e.g. spaces or anything that isn't a letter or number) then you need to surround the object name with square brackets. So your command line would become something like this:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "<connection-string>" 
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models 
    -table "[dbo].[My Company$Customer]"
```

You strictly don't need the square brackets around the schema (`dbo`) but there's no harm in including them there too.

Answer (score 3):

With EF Core 3.1 I had to escape the $ character.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=myServer;Database=myDB;User Id=sa;Password=xyz;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -table "[dbo].[My Company`$Product]"
```